# Rotate label and label font size

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to rotate the label for the right arrow such that it aligns with the arrow. Also I am looking for a way to change the font size of the labels without using \small oder \tiny. Last but not least I would like to make the circles around B and C smaller. I have already tried so much but nothing really worked out as expected.

Every answer is appreciated!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 60]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={80pt,between origins},row
  sep={80pt,between origins},nodes={asymmetrical rectangle}] (s)
{
  & |[name=A,draw,rectangle]| A & |[name=B,draw,circle]| B \\
  & |[name=D,draw,rectangle]| D & |[name=C,draw,circle]| C \\
};
\draw [->] 
  (A) edge node[auto] {\small Reduktion} (B) 
  (B) edge node[auto, rotate=-90] {\small Annahme}(C) 
  (C) edge node[auto] {\small Erwartung}(D) 
;
\draw[->, line join=round, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=10, amplitude=1.9,post=lineto, post length=4pt}]
  (A) -- (D)  
;  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

At the moment it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Please extend your code to make it a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}` so that we don't have to look for packages and libraries you used into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: roate label]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,matrix,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 60]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={80pt,between origins},row
  sep={80pt,between origins}] (s)
{
  & |[name=A,draw,rectangle]| A & |[name=B,draw,circle,inner sep=2pt]| B \\
  & |[name=D,draw,rectangle]| D & |[name=C,draw,circle,inner sep=2pt]| C \\
};
\draw [->] 
  (A) edge node[auto] {\small Reduktion} (B) 
  (B) edge node[auto, rotate=-90,midway, above] {\small Annahme}(C) 
  (C) edge node[auto] {\small Erwartung}(D) 
;
\draw[->, line join=round, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=10, amplitude=1.9,post=lineto, post length=4pt}]
  (A) -- (D)  
;  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```